# A function uses an object to initiate and destroy a resource. How can I rewrite this as HOF that provides a resource?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Here is what I am starting with. `convert` uses svgInjector to initiate and destroy a resource.

```
export async function convert(
  serializedSvg: string,
  svgSourceId: string,
  containerId: string
): Promise<string> {
  const svgInjector = new SvgInjector(serializedSvg, containerId).inject();
  if (!svgInjector.injectedElement) {
    throw new Error("Svg not injected");
  }

  const doc = new TargetDocument({});
  const xml = convertRecursively(
    svgInjector.injectedElement,
    doc,
    {
      svgSourceId,
    }
  );

  svgInjector.remove();

  return doc.saveXML();
}
```

How can I rewrite this to instead have a higher order function initiate, provide and destroy the resource `svgInjector.injectedElement` to the convert function?

**EDIT:**

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```js
var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text x="20" y="20">I am made available in DOM</text></svg>'

function convert(
  serializedSvg,
  containerId
) {
  // make resource available (cross-cutting convern)
  var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
  var resource = new DOMParser().parseFromString(serializedSvg, "image/svg+xml").documentElement;
  container.appendChild(resource);

  // core convert functionality does things with resource
  console.log(resource.getBBox())
  
  // clean up resource (cross-cutting concern)
  resource.remove()
}

convert(svg, "container")
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Minimal</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is a TypeScript version of the JavaScript in the previous edit

```
var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text x="20" y="20">I am made available in DOM</text></svg>'

function convert(
  serializedSvg: string,
  containerId: string
) {
  // make resource available (cross-cutting convern)
  var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
  if (!(container instanceof HTMLDivElement)) {
    throw new Error("Extpected a div element")
  }
  var resource = new DOMParser().parseFromString(serializedSvg, "image/svg+xml").documentElement;
  if (!(resource instanceof SVGSVGElement)) {
    throw new Error("Extpected a svg element")
  }
  container.appendChild(resource);

  // core convert functionality does things with resource
  console.log(resource.getBBox())

  // clean up resource (cross-cutting concern)
  resource.remove()
}

convert(svg, "container")
```

Comment: Could you make this code a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE?  Right now `SvgInjector`, `TargetDocument`, `convertRecursively`, and anything that depends on them are not defined, so to even begin looking at this, I'd need to either remove these or define them.  The same goes for the answer below.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz: Thank you for looking at my question! I have added a minimal reproducible example. Let me know if you think anything is missing.

Comment: If I drop that code into [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) I get several errors; are you asking about those errors?  If not, could you fix them?

Comment: @jcalz: See my second edit. Thank you again! I was not asking about those errors. I think that the errors are because the first edit had a JavaScript version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the sort of thing you're looking for exactly, but I'd be inclined to invert the control flow so that `convert()` uses or is passed a "resource manager" which takes care of the creation, furnishing, and deletion of the resource.  A `ResourceManager` could simply be a function like:

```
type ResourceManager<T, I> = <R>(initProps: I, cb: (resource: T) => R) => R;
```

So a `ResourceManager<T, I>` is a function that takes some initial property bag of type `I` to specify which resource of type `T` is needed, and a callback function that does the actual work after the resource is available and before it is destroyed.  If the callback function returns a result, then so does the resource manager.

This `ResourceManager<T, I>` is the generic contract that can be reused for different types of resource.  Of course different types of resource need their own implementations.  For example, I'd pull out of your `convert()` function a `ResourceManager<SVGSVGElement, { serializedSvg: string, containerId: string }>` like this:

```
const svgManager: ResourceManager<SVGSVGElement, { serializedSvg: string, containerId: string }> =
  (initProps, cb) => {

    // make resource available)
    var container = document.getElementById(initProps.containerId);
    if (!(container instanceof HTMLDivElement)) {
      throw new Error("Extpected a div element");
    }
    var resource = new DOMParser().parseFromString(initProps.serializedSvg, "image/svg+xml").documentElement;
    if (!(resource instanceof SVGSVGElement)) {
      throw new Error("Extpected a svg element")
    }
    container.appendChild(resource);

    // core functionality
    const ret = cb(resource);

    // clean up resource
    resource.remove()

    // return returned value if we have one
    return ret;
  }
```

Notice how the "core functionality" is just deferred to the callback, whose return value is held onto in case it is needed.  Then `convert()` is simplified to:

```
function convert(
  serializedSvg: string,
  containerId: string
) {
  svgManager({ serializedSvg, containerId }, (resource => console.log(resource.getBBox())));
}
```

Where `resource => console.log(resource.getBBox())` is the function that does the work without caring about how to get or dispose of `resource`.

---

Hope that helps or gives you some ideas.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAzsDmEF4IHIA8N4A8C2AbAdlAgEQAWALuQA4BcA9HQO7MB0jAzCwPZix0BMABmF0MxAHypyAU0zkImEkOIQAnksESAkhBDYI2EABNpu0AEtcIAEa5T5-BAAiAeQCyqOjLmTRcccgAUIHkqlSmAErSUFwArmAAxtJuIPggsNJgqAAqADQQWuKIEKgR4gAUDubkAApgXFRQNAX5CdbN5WDRcYnSzdkAlIhFEUMIIwDcwQlchPIYKWkZYM1RMfFJi+mZqADKAGoA4geHAKJ22NL45PkA3tCZ5iC45gBe0ka7cM1Q5GAOsFas3IIAcmS0Rh+fwBEAAvkUEIEIBBKvhqnUGlBWtYxkVbsFkciGAYQABrUxdda9Mygqy2aQDJGE0CQGbXUH4TLFIxcBKxS7XFgZcjnaQC8gAIVUENR6PqjRYbJBYLAEIGU0JEHMADMUQBCcpKjlchy-VJJLi6gAS2TcABknOZgKLxQMhvjNcjyKR6owIJy-acwPUwOViKc5OEEjIjLoIEYnRBpBcruRiOqmcjYZmICyIJSekligHnO4auAoJlygMWFQK9IAGL1bC7aH4WCy2ryqAsSv-Z5vD5fQEQYjmQwZPywADUOFw6ZYPL54pdqY1hJ1+s63Q29jm5uklogJxOq+ubogHs93t9-ukgeDPDDEeo0mjHzjGCTKeu6Zz2c1I0VRYEAqHCfAjAAYVISwjG3KkkgzHNiRmLoIG1WJ8GjcxZgHUIczZX582keQkDaeDCwZKZkLoCAEjsVIIFiKhiIQ6QcwLXcWC6bAuGAaRqwJQliS6ch4kcUTxI-UBcFiexdUYUxSBAfiIFmdjNUksAJJI9ds0CDCsPIHDHDZfiwHIcomT7J4XneT5vmgNtASZIDOVVSEnP+dtAnday4C2ZZynuGyB3s4cgXZFUIThfIKN3YY6NmGI7BYXAuA7TjeiFEiJQlLhMGrN0M30szMksjB8mINzMnTajgkCIA)

Comment: Thank you for giving it a shot. I have upvoted your answer. I'll think about it some more and hopefully come back to this question again soon

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best attempt so far. I hope someone smarter posts a better solution.

Two weaknesses of the solution below I see are:

- The typing of the enhancer is not generic, hindering reuse
- The enhancer requires binding, hindering enhancer compose

```
    type Props = {
      svg: SVGSVGElement;
      svgSourceId: string;
      containerId: string;
    };

    async function convertBase(props: Props): Promise<string> {
      const doc = new TargetDocument({});
      const xml = convertRecursively(props.svg, doc, {
        svgSourceId: props.svgSourceId,
      });

      return doc.saveXML();
    }

    type EnhancerProps = {
      serializedSvg: string;
      svgSourceId: string;
      containerId: string;
    };

    type EnhancerPropsLight = {
      svgSourceId: string;
      containerId: string;
    };

    function enhancer(fn: Function, props: EnhancerProps) {
      const rest = omit(["serializedSvg"])(props) as EnhancerPropsLight;
      const svgInjector = new SvgInjector(
        props.serializedSvg,
        props.containerId
      ).inject();
      if (!svgInjector.injectedElement) {
        throw new Error("Svg not injected");
      }

      const res = convertToTgmlBase({ ...rest, svg: svgInjector.injectedElement });

      svgInjector.remove();

      return res;
    }

    const convert = enhancer.bind(null, convertBase);
    export { convert };
```